# Constructing object in two ways without heap

Tags: c++, embedded

Is it possible to provide two constructors:

```
Object(Obj & obj1, Obj & obj2);
```

and

```
Object(int obj1_initval, int obj2_initval);
```

and in the second case, obj1 and obj2 will be allocated to .bss at compile time?

This is going to be used in bare metal system, where we can't afford a heap.

Comment: Maybe, it depends *very* much on the compiler and linker you're using, and how you "allocate" the objects.

Comment: up-to-date gcc ecosystem for ARMs in general, but I would not like to use it if it is based on a very compiler specific feature. Also, objects are always created statically.

Comment: A specific constructor bears no relevance whatsoever as to where its parameters come from. Feel free to provide `obj1` and `obj2` from the heap, stack, or carrier pigeons. C++ doesn't care. There are two parameters called `obj1` and `obj2` that are passed by reference. That's all the constructor knows or cares about. The End.

Comment: There are four storage duration models in C++. Your constructor overloads do not have anything to do with them. Standard C++ doesn't know what _.bss_ is either.

Comment: Are you looking for an `Object` which contains two `Obj`s (as member) vs. another which just refers to two instances of `Obj`. This sounds a bit similar like `std::string_view` vs. `std::string`. May be, you have to design a non-owning base class (e.g. `ObjectView`) and an owning derived class (e.g. `Object`) whereby free-standing functions may take `ObjectView` when actual storage is not a subject.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, yes, I am fully aware of this. I just want to make object responsible for creating this objects when using second constructor, without using heap, so preferably at compile time, .bss is mentioned only as low level implication of what I'd like to achieve.

Comment: Yes, you can pass them as temporaries, which will not be allocated on the heap; however only `const` references can bind to temporaries, so either change the first constructor to take `const` references, or rvalue references. P.S. There's nothing in the question that actually explains you want your 2nd constructor to delegate to the first one. The mention of "second one" looks like a natural typo, meaning "first one". The best way to have a best chance of getting an answer to your question is to make it clear exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Constructors have nothing to do with whether objects are allocated on the heap or not. You allocate objects on the heap using `new`, if you are not using `new` (directly or indirectly) you are not allocating objects on the heap.

Of course there are other ways of allocating heap memory, `malloc` in C for instance. But the same principal applies, C++ won't make heap allocations for you.

Comment: Just to clarify, using the language itself won't, but the libraries you use might.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for an object which does refer to other objects which are or are not contained as members.

This reminds me to `std::string_view` vs. `std::string`.

To achieve this, the class `Object` which stores instances of `Obj` internally may be derived from a base class `ObjectView` which only refers to instances of `Obj` (which have to be stored anywhere).

A little sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Obj {
  private:
    std::string _name;
  public:
    Obj(const std::string &name): _name(name) { }

    const std::string& getName() const { return _name; }
};

class ObjectView {
  private:
    Obj &_obj1, &_obj2;
  public:
    ObjectView(Obj &obj1, Obj &obj2): _obj1(obj1), _obj2(obj2) { }

    Obj& getObj1() { return _obj1; }
    Obj& getObj2() { return _obj2; }
};

class Object: public ObjectView {
  private:
    Obj _obj1, _obj2;
  public:
    Object(const std::string &name1, const std::string &name2):
      ObjectView(_obj1, _obj2),
      _obj1(name1), _obj2(name2)
    { }
};

void print(const char *name, ObjectView &objView)
{
  std::cout << "ObjectView " << name << " { "
    << "obj1: " << objView.getObj1().getName() << ", "
    << "obj2: " << objView.getObj2().getName() << " }\n";
}

int main()
{
  Object object1("o11", "o12");
  print("object1", object1);
  Obj obj1("o21"), obj2("o22");
  ObjectView object2(obj1, obj2);
  print("object2", object2);
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
ObjectView object1 { obj1: o11, obj2: o12 }
ObjectView object2 { obj1: o21, obj2: o22 }
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de28208ea92723e6)</kbd>